# Почему не загружаются изображения?

Tags: php, upload, php7

Здравствуйте. На локальном серере изображения нормально загружаются, на vds, не грузятся. В консоле выходит ошибка, но просмотреть детальную информацию не могу, `falled to load response data` пишет. Поменял `upload_max_filesize` и `post_max_filesize` на 20 мегабайт. Но всеравно та же проблема. Может то что разница в версия php? На локальном сервере 5.6, на vds 7.0.
Помогите в чем может быть проблема?

UPD:
Нашел вроде проблему. В логе вот что написано.
`[2016-10-13 15:23:41] local.ERROR: Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException: Can't write image data to path (/home/user/site.name/public_html/public/upload/img/44761_20161013152341.jpg) in /home/user/site.name/public_html/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php:143
Stack trace:`
Права на запись вроде есть.

Comment: у вебсервера другое имя пользователя, вероятно права на запись есть у вас, но не у него.

Comment: Как это можно узнать? И как это исправить?)

Comment: Какая ос и веб-сервер ?

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin ubuntu 16.04 | apache 2.4

Comment: попробуйте проверить /etc/apache2/apache2.conf и посмотреть User и Group, затем сменить владельца, ниже описал примерно последовательность

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте проверить права на запись для данной директории.

1. Узнайте пользователя, под которым работает веб-сервер. 
   для `apache` в конфиге `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` посмотреть/поправить на `User` и `Group`, для `nginx` в конфиге `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` посмотреть/поправить `user`
2. Проверьте кто является владельцем папки. Например `ls -al` выполнить в директории `/home/user/site.name/public_html/public/`.
3. Сменить права на директорию. `chown -R User:Group /home/user/site.name/public_html/public/upload/`, где `User` и `Group` пользователь и группа веб-сервера
4. Добавить права на запись, например: `chmod -R u+w home/user/site.name/public_html/public/upload/`

Comment: У апача пользователь и группа `root` у папки с сайтом вот что `
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data user 4096 окт 13 14:25 site.name` Если поставить пользователя рут для папки с сайтом, то по sftp я не смогу загружать и заменять файлы. Как тут быть?)

Comment: Попробуйте проверить в  `/etc/passwd` есть ли пользователь `www-data` и измените пользователя апачу на `www-data`, перезапустите апач `systemctl restart apache2`.

Comment: Если пользователя не окажется, можно апачу назначить пользователя, под которым входите, но не советую. Лучше всего будет создать отдельно пользователя [вот инструкция](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно директории куда загружается изображения дать права для группы www-data(в которой собственно состоит одноименный пользователь апача)