# Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, сервер, права

Установил `apache2`, `php7` на выделенном сервере. Создал вручную файл `1.txt` и пытаюсь записать в него данные - `file_put_contents("1.txt", data);`.. но выдает ошибку:

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(1.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/1.php on line 3
```

также не удается создать файл через `php`

`ls -l`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 webuser webuser   65 окт 17 15:53 1.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 webuser webuser    0 окт 17 15:55 1.txt
```

как вы видите установлены права `644`.

как решить эту проблему?? значит ли это, что я должен выдать файлам права `777`?

**смотрю у хостинга, там создаются файлы с правами `644`, и легко редактируется через `php`**

прошу разъяснить

Comment: Файл `1.txt` должен быть доступен для записи, соответственно, нужны права на чтение и запись.

Comment: он и доступен для записи..разве права `644` не дают доступ для записи владельцу?

Comment: От какого пользователя запускается php скрипт? Какая у него рабочая директория? Изменится-ли что-то если указать абсолютный путь к файлу?

Comment: php запущен он рута; та же, где и лежит сайт; ничего не изменилось

Comment: Права должны быть на запись и на чтение пользователем, под которым запущен апач. Кроме того, у него должны быть права на запись в директории.

Comment: при каждом создании файла придется лезть в терминал и давать ему права 777? даже тогда, когда php создаст файл?  как же тогда это делают на хостингах... там, при создании файла им присваиваются права 644, не больше

Comment: Недавно [вопрос был подобный](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577510/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/577541#577541) с проблемами с правами. И да, права 777 выдавать не стоит точно. Почитайте лучше как свой веб-сервер развернуть, я бы еще посоветовал либо apache2 спрятать за nginx, либо совсем отказаться от него.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. Еще вопрос, а лучше для ftp аккаунтов использовать виртуальных пользователей? или же напрямую через системных.. vsftpd

Comment: С начала выполныть
```sudo su```
Потом можно

Comment: `sudo -i` лучше, чем `sudo su`

Answer (score 5):

Если работаете под Linux и редактируете файлы при помощи SFTP, то проверьте, от имени кого был создан файл(и кто им, соответственно, владеет). Обычно в FPT-клиентах с поддержкой SFTP файлы создаются от пользователя root. Естественно, что пользователь www-data(под которым должен быть запущен и Apache/nginx, и PHP/PHP-FPM) не может получить доступ к файлу, которым владеет root. Для решения этой проблемы нужно присвоить файлу/папке нового владельца:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Comment: спасибо, сутки парился не получалось ничего, ошибок тьма было, в моем случае помогла команда chown -R www-root:www-root /var/www