# Работа с файлами php

Tags: php

Не видит файл.

> Warning:file_put_contents(test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 15

```
<?php
 error_reporting(-1);


 $counter_file = 'test.txt';

 if (!is_file($counter_file)) {
   $counter = 0;
 } else {
   $counter = file_get_contents($counter_file);
 }

 $counter++;

file_put_contents($counter_file, $counter);

?>
```

Comment: `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/'. $counter_file);`

Comment: нет у текущей учетки прав на запись в файл.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579402/failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Выполните в директории файла команду

```
sudo chmod 777 test.txt
```